# Make divs on a page print on seperate pages when printed

Tags: javascript, printing

I have Divs of different sizes that are generated by user input, I need them to be printed in different pages when printed. Like for example Div1 takes up 1.5 pages, and div2 takes up .5 i need Div2 to print on a new page instead of simply starting at the second half of the second page, starting where Div1 left off.
How would i accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include separate stylesheets for screens (monitors, phones, tablets, etc.) and printing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="screen_style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print_style.css">
```

Then you can use [CSS page breaks](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-breaks) in the print stylesheet to specify a page break before and/or after each relevant `div`.

Comment: Didn't know there is `page-break-before` before I saw this. Great info.

Comment: Didn't know page-break was even possible till now. Thanks!